# How can I detect japanese text in a Java string?

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

I need to be able to detect Japanese characters in a Java string.

Currently I'm getting the UnicodeBlock and checking to see if it's equal to Character.UnicodeBlock.KATAKANA or Character.UnicodeBlock.HALFWIDTH_AND_FULLWIDTH_FORMS, but I'm not 100% that's going to cover everything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

I use the following java method. Might not completely address your requirement though.

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
/**
 * Returns if a character is one of Chinese-Japanese-Korean characters.
 * 
 * @param c
 *            the character to be tested
 * @return true if CJK, false otherwise
 */
private boolean isCharCJK(final char c) {
    if ((Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS)
            || (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS_EXTENSION_A)
            || (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS_EXTENSION_B)
            || (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_COMPATIBILITY_FORMS)
            || (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_COMPATIBILITY_IDEOGRAPHS)
            || (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_RADICALS_SUPPLEMENT)
            || (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_SYMBOLS_AND_PUNCTUATION)
            || (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.ENCLOSED_CJK_LETTERS_AND_MONTHS)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Futhermore, these seem they should work for Hiragana and Katakana characters:

```
private boolean isHiragana(final char c)
{
     return (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c)==Character.UnicodeBlock.HIRAGANA);
}

private boolean isKatakana(final char c)
{
     return (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c)==Character.UnicodeBlock.KATAKANA);
}
```

Comment: This seems to fail to detect some Japanese and Korean characters. I ended up combining this with https://gist.github.com/TheFinestArtist/2fd1b4aa1d4824fcbaef

Answer (score 7):

According [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), Japanese isn't made of one script: *"There is no Japanese Unicode script. Instead, Unicode offers the Hiragana, Katakana, Han and Latin scripts that Japanese documents are usually composed of."*

In which case, this regex should do the trick:

```
yourString.matches("[\\p{Hiragana}\\p{Katakana}\\p{Han}\\p{Latin}]*+")
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise enough ... I want to detect Japanese CHARACTERS in a string, not the character set name.

Comment: Including Latin will match most European languages as well, which I don't think is what the OP wants to check for (although Japanese is sometimes written with Roman characters as well).

Comment: Han are Chinese characters as well, but I believe you do want to add Hiragana.

Comment: That's right, there's no way to really know. This character in a string 本 - could be part of chinese or japanese text. And it's neither hiragana nor katakana of any width.